# Can I use htredirect to index in the same folder?

Tags: php, redirect, url-rewriting

I have been building a new admin system and using and directory /admin2/ to store the files while testing.
I have been using redirects such as `RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)[/]?$ /admin2/index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]` during testing and that has been working fine.
Now I am ready to push the new system live and I would prefer to move the files to just /admin/ but when I try to use a redirect like `RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)[/]?$ /admin/index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]` it gives me a configuration error.
Can I not redirect to the index page in the same folder?  Is that not allowed?

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: i think its redirects and redirects again and again.

Comment: perhaps you must add this line before your RewriteRule:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !admin/index\.php$

Comment: After further testing the individual redirects work fine. Things like `RewriteRule ^admin/events[/]?$ /admin/index.php?page=events [NC,L]`.  It is just the fallback one that causes the error.